# adding 2 large integer with array

Tags: c++

ive been trying to add 2 large integer on c++ using array and the output is always 0000 and i cant identified the problem

what im trying to achieve is like 30000000000 + 50000000 = 30050000000.

and this is the code that i wrote
, can anyone help me trying to figure it out why the output is 0000?

````
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


int array1[100];
int array2[100];
int hasil[100];
int func1(int n)
{   
    int b;
    while(b>0)
    b=sizeof(array1[100]);
    array1[b]=n%10;
    n=n/10;
    b--;
}

int func2(int p)
{
    int b;
    while(b>0)
    b=sizeof(array1[100]);
    array2[b]=p%10;
    p=p/10;
    b--;
}


int func3(int i)
{   int satuan,puluhan,bil;
    for(i=sizeof(array2[100]);i>0;i--)
    {
        int bil = array1[100]+array2[100];
        satuan=bil%10;
        hasil[i]=satuan+puluhan;
        puluhan=bil/10;

    }
}

int main ()
{   int n,p,i;
    int func1(n);
    int func2(p);
    int func3(i);
    int satuan=0;
    int puluhan=0;

    int x,y;

    cout<<"masukan bilangan pertama = ";
    cin>>n; cout<<endl;

    cout<<"masukan bilangan ke dua = ";
    cin>>p; cout<<endl;



    for(x=sizeof(hasil[100]);x>0;x--)       
    {   
        y=0;
        cout<<hasil[y];
        y++;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: what i mean by sizeof(array1[100]); is the lenght of array.

Comment: You are not calling the functions func1, func2, func3. And y = 0 always. while loops in func1 and func2 need braces{}.

Comment: `30'000'000'000` is too big for typical 32-bit int. Use `long long` or better `std::int64_t`

Comment: Also, `sizeof(array)` will not return number of elements. `func1` and `func2` have infinite loops. You are using your variables initialized most of the time.

Comment: `while(b>0)
    b=sizeof(array1[100]);` is infinite loop (and UB (from the loop and from the fact your read uninitialized variable)).

Comment: Honestly, I'm not trying to discourage you, but personally I'd ditch this code and write it again, piece by piece. Write the minimal piece of reading input from user. Test it. Write first function, check if it works correctly. Test each function and fix any issues you find before writing more code. Try to test them extensively - the more you test, the easier it is to find bugs, and finding bugs early is *way* easier than late.

Comment: thx for the time and answer guys, im gonna write the code from the scratch again